# error processing remote manifest

Tags: 20.04, backup, duplicity

I am running Ubuntu 20.4 LTS and I am having the following issue from past 3 days. whenever the Backup starts I get the following error message:

(duplicity-inc.20200825t060008z.to.20200826t052304z.manifest.gpg): gpg failed, see log below:
===== begin gnupg log =====
gpg: decrypt_message failed: unknown system error
===== end gnupg log =====
how this issue can be resolved? I am not able to take backup nor restore any thing?  any help would be greatly appreciated.